# Logging not creating file

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Right now im copying a code to test the logging module of python:

```
import logging

# Gets or creates a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  

# set log level
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

# define file handler and set formatter
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logfile.log')
formatter    = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add file handler to logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# Logs
logger.debug('A debug message')
logger.info('An info message')
logger.warning('Something is not right.')
logger.error('A Major error has happened.')
logger.critical('Fatal error. Cannot continue')
```

And for some reason the file is not created, and i cant figure out why... help please!.

I just realized it doesnt even log on the console, unless i add something after the import like "logging.info('example)"... then the logs on #Logs show up in the console, still no file is generated... whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `file_handler.setLevel(...)` before logging anything and adding the handler.

```
# set log level
file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
# add file handler to logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

This way you are going to ensure the new handler also gets setting for a particular level.

Each handler can have a different logging level.

Comment: hello! i tried your solution but still doesnt work, the file is not created.

Comment: Are you setting the level before adding the handler to the logger?

Comment: yes i am, i added just under the "file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)" line

Comment: Have confirmed the behaviour starting from a fresh environment? Is your code part of a larger codebase?

Comment: @JoaquinDiaz: did you solve your issue? Did my answer help?

Comment: hey i solved it, i mean i worked around it, for some reason when i tried to create an logging object like "logger" it wouldnt work well, but if i did the same config just on "logging" it worked.